# Users who can see deleted messages can one-box them in chat

Tags: bug, chat

If a user can see a deleted message (either because it's his own message or he's a room owner or moderator), then if he posts a link to the message, it will one-box in chat, even though it's deleted. If another user (who can't see the deleted message) posts the same link, then it will not one-box and will just show the link text.

For example: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15281270#15281270

This is probably not intended.

Comment: This seems fixed now.